# Webpack dev server stops serve asset after wrong module path

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

There is basic webpack project with webpack dev server. Everything works fine until change some module import with wrong path or name.

**webpack.config.js**:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/main.js',
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        clean: true
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource'
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'webpack playground'
        })
    ]
}
```

Dev dependencies in **package.json**:

```
"html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.1",
"webpack": "^5.28.0",
"webpack-cli": "^4.6.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
```

**./src/main.js**:

```
import SomeImg from './someimg.jpg';

const element = document.createElement('div');
const myIcon = new Image();
myIcon.src = SomeImg;
element.appendChild(myIcon);
document.body.appendChild(element);
```

**There is someimg.jpg** in src directory.

Problem reproduces by next steps:

1. Run in terminal `npx webpack serve`. Result: `Compiled successfully`. `someimg.jpg` displays at the page and visible as a source in Chrome DevTools (with hashed hame).
2. In `./src/main.js` change `import SomeImg from './someimg.jpg';` to `import SomeImg from './someimg-wrong-name.jpg';`. Obvious result in terminal:

```
***************
ERROR in ./src/main.js 1:0-47
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './someimg-wrong-name.jpg' in '*******'
***************
Failed to compile.
```

3. Change `import SomeImg from './someimg-wrong-name.jpg';` back to `import SomeImg from './someimg.jpg';`. Result in terminal: `Compiled successfully`, but in Chrome console I get `http://127.0.0.1:8080/3de22ea07be845d3db63.jpg 404 (Not Found)`, the image doesn't display, and there is no jpg file in Chrome DevTools Source tab (only `index` and `main.bundle.js`).

After restart `npx webpack serve` everything is fine again. Did I miss some configuration? Can dev server handle this situation without restart?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with

```
module.exports = {
    ****************
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        writeToDisk: true
    },
    *****************
}
```

in `webpack.config.js`.

Looks like an acceptable solution, but is there a way to keep assets in memory without writing to disk?